# Recover partition table from running system and encrypted disk

Tags: data-recovery, luks, fdisk, gdisk

I've made a small mistake, I've removed my boot partition by mistake.
Using `testdisk` I was able to recover the boot partition without problem but I either misused it or did not understand and only write partition table with my boot partition.
So now my `/` and `swap` partition are missing from my system.
I've found this [answer from the great Gilles](https://superuser.com/a/217392/264697) however,
my system is using EFI and my partition is encrypted, does the same solution apply to restore my partition table and what partition format should I use with an encrypted `ext4` and `swap` partition ?

Also in the same question from SuperUser, I've come accross the fact that I should use `gdisk` and substract 1 to sector size is all those informations accurate and up-to-date ?

Edit 1:

`testdisk` find those partition with a deep search:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1 - 512 GB / 476 GiB - CHS 488386 64 32
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
 P EFI System                  2048    1619967    1617920 [EFI System Partition] [ESP]
 D MS Data                     2054    1619973    1617920 [NO NAME]
 D EFI System                  4096     618495     614400 [EFI System Partition]
 D MS Data                     4102     618501     614400
 D MS Data                    37699      43872       6174
 D MS Data                    43872      50045       6174 [Boot]
 D Linux filesys. data       618494 1000206893  999588400
 D Linux filesys. data       618496     622591       4096
 D Linux filesys. data       618496 1000206895  999588400
 D MS Data                374180459  374183338       2880 [NO NAME]
 D MS Data                374180483  374183362       2880 [NO NAME]
 D MS Data                374181379  374184258       2880 [NO NAME]
>D Linux filesys. data    965039160  965043255       4096
```

2 of them (the one with 4096 block size) as LUKS.

howerver with `"bad structue"` and from this mess I've know Idea what I could or should restore.
My orginal disk had a gpt boot partiton, one main encrypted partition and a encrypted swap partition in the end.

My computer is still on and I've been able to backup LUKS header and I have access to all data and relevant informations, I just don't know how to exploit it.

Comment: If not rebooted recover partition:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10364557&postcount=34 Do not know LVM, but most installs use ESP, /boot & a large partition that then contains the LVM volumes. Some now do not use /boot as it can be inside the LVM with newest systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I've used `testdisk` to solve the issue I've identify my other partition :

```
#main partition
/sys/class/block/nvme0n1p2/start                                                                                                                                                                      
618496
/sys/class/block/nvme0n1p2/size                                                                                                                                                                       
964420664
#Swap partition
/sys/class/block/nvme0n1p3/start                                                                                                                                                                      
965039160
/sys/class/block/nvme0n1p3/size                                                                                                                                                                       
35167740
```

So with that in mind I needed to identify my boot drive properly in `testdisk` and it was this one :

```
 D EFI System                  4096     618495     614400 [EFI System Partition]
```

I selected this selection and add two other partition corresponding to the value found in `/sys/class/block`.
`testdisk` uses start and end sector not start sector and count. So to find end sector you need to add comute `start+count-1`.

As partition type I chooses Luks partition in linux subcategorie. Et voilà.